# Is there a way to add array elements into a SESSION variable?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a #php shopping cart function which adds the item to the `$_SESSION['cart']` array. the function works properly in the localhost (XAMPP Server) but not in an Online server.
here is the code:

When a visitor clicks the "ADD TO CART" button, the function is called.

```
public function add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $size){
    session_start();
    $cart_item = array("id"=>$product_id, "quantity"=>$quantity,"size"=>$size);
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] =  $cart_item;
}
```

When insert an item inside this function manually, it works both on localhost and server:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['abc2'] = array("id"=>"abc2", "quantity"=>"2", "size"=>"L");
```

$_SESSION['cart'] is defined as:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
```

Comment: How is the PHP function called? Why is your cart handled on the server side? From my experience, this is usually mainly handled client side until checkout.

Comment: you are right, cart is handled on the client side. There is no problem with PHP function call. since, I have embedded a manual item inside the function and it worked.

Comment: What you are saying and what your code is showing contradict each-other. PHP is a server side language, not a client side language.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about doing a server-side cart, it's just a little slower in my experience but has access to session vs. client-side cookies. That being said, you should not be putting `session_start()` in any conditional statement or optional function like you have it. It's better that it be set at the top of every page that uses a session.

Comment: I just fixed it. Thank Grumpy for making me pay attention to my function. I just noticed that I was pushing elements inside session array first making them clear of escape characters. (Mysql_real_escape_string(); )